# Show frame rate in DDMS

Tags: android, ddms, frame-rate

As I wanted to compare several apps according to their graphics performance, I wanted to measure the frame rate for each app. In DDMS I discovered a tab "System Information" where I can choose "CPU load", "Memory usage" or "Frame render time".
When I select the first two options a graph gets displayed on the right. But for "Frame render time" somehow I get no data displayed (of course I already tried to click the button "Update from Device" but that didn't change anything).

I found no instruction how to use this tool. All instructions are missing exactly this topic... -_-
So what am I missing? How can I display the frame render time in DDMS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22998964/660408