# Writing a script to output Frame rate/dropped frame statistics on Android

Tags: android, graphics, gpu

I would like to analyze the maximum frame rate when I run a few applications such as games and videos. I'm pretty new to Android so I'm not sure where I should start.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tool will help you:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/gltracer.html

You need device with api level **16** or higher.